# how to enable / disable option button in excel

Tags: excel, radio-button

I have a problem resolving one issue in excel, hope if I can get help

I have three option buttons in my excel I want these option buttons to be enable if corresponding cells say (D1 for option button1, D2 for option button 2 and D3 for option button 3) has some values, if empty than corresponding option button to be disable, can you help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
If Cells(1, 4).Value <> Cells(1, 1).Value Then
    Selection.Enabled = True
Else
    Selection.Enabled = False code here
End If
```

Here I compare the value of D1 cell with the value of A1 cell.
Hope it helps you!!!